# US layover as dual Dominican German citizen without visa in either passport

Tags: usa, passports, dual-nationality, german-citizens, dominican-citizens

I'm a student currently living in S. Korea and I have double nationality: Dominican and German. I want to travel back to my country but through Europe is much more expensive than laying over in the US. However, I don't have VISA for the US in any of both passports. I would like to layover in the US with the German passport since I can only do an ESTA form and it seems easier and quicker.

However, I want to be sure that I can travel as follows: Going out of Korea with my Dominican passport, entering/exiting the US with my German passport with ESTA form and entering my country with my Dominican passport.
And if so, should I book my airplane ticket with my Dominican passport information? (Since it's the final destination).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is very common to use two passports too.

What you will do for *immigration officials* is:

- Depart South Korea using the same passport you entered. This is the passport containing your student visa (but you didn't say which).
- Transit the US on your German passport.
- Arrive on your Dominican passport.

But note that *the airline* needs to see both passports. You will explain to them that you will transit the US on your German passport.

Comment: She could even leave with the German passport if South Korea doesn't stamp on exit